# Quiz project with XML and Java

Tags: java, performance, beginner, android, quiz

I'm learning to code Android apps and have recently finished a quiz app. I would like some feedback about best practices and possible ways to improve performance, as I'm also new to Java.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.example.android.mathquiz.MainActivity"
    android:background="#C5CAE9">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <TextView
            style="@style/AllElements"
            android:text="Respondé las siguientes preguntas:" />

        <!-- QUESTION 1 [DONE]-->
        <TextView
            style="@style/Questions"
            android:text="1) La pendiente de una recta es su inclinación." />

        <RadioGroup
            style="@style/AllElements"
            android:id="@+id/question_one_answers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_one_answer_one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Verdadero"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_one_answer_two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Falso"/>
        </RadioGroup>

    <!-- QUESTION 2 [LISTO]-->
    <TextView
        style="@style/Questions"
        android:text="2) Indicar la ordenada al origen de la función:\ny = x" />

    <EditText
        style="@style/AllElements"
        android:id="@+id/question_two_answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Respuesta"/>

    <!-- QUESTION 3 [LISTO]-->
    <TextView
        style="@style/Questions"
        android:text="3) Indicar la pendiente de la función:\ny = x + 1" />

    <EditText
        style="@style/AllElements"
        android:id="@+id/question_three_answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Respuesta"/>

    <!-- QUESTION 4 -->
    <TextView
        style="@style/Questions"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:text="4) ¿Cuáles son los requisitos de las funciones?" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/AllElements"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="Seleccionar todas las opciones posibles." />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/question_four_answer_one"
        style="@style/AllElements"
        android:text="Unicidad" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/question_four_answer_two"
        style="@style/AllElements"
        android:text="Positividad" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/question_four_answer_three"
        style="@style/AllElements"
        android:text="Existencia" />

    <!-- CHECK ANSWERS -->
    <Button
        style="@style/AllElements"
        android:text="Revisar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:onClick="checkAnswers"/>


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] correctAnswers = {"Falso", "0", "1", "Unicidad Existencia"};

    RadioGroup questionOneAnswers;

    RadioButton questionOneAnswerOne;
    RadioButton questionOneAnswerTwo;
    EditText questionTwoAnswer;
    EditText questionThreeAnswer;
    CheckBox questionFourAnswerOne;
    CheckBox questionFourAnswerTwo;
    CheckBox questionFourAnswerThree;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // QUESTION 1
        questionOneAnswerOne = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.question_one_answer_one);
        questionOneAnswerTwo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.question_one_answer_two);

        // QUESTION 2
        questionTwoAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question_two_answer);

        // QUESTION 3
        questionThreeAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question_three_answer);

        // QUESTION 4
        questionFourAnswerOne = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_four_answer_one);
        questionFourAnswerTwo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_four_answer_two);
        questionFourAnswerThree = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_four_answer_three);

        questionOneAnswers = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.question_one_answers);

    }

    private boolean isEmpty(EditText myeditText) {
        return myeditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
    }

    private String questionOneGetAnswer() {
        if (questionOneAnswerOne.isChecked()) {
            return questionOneAnswerOne.getText().toString();
        }

        else if (questionOneAnswerTwo.isChecked()) {
            return questionOneAnswerTwo.getText().toString();
        }

        else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private String questionTwoGetAnswer() {
        if (!isEmpty(questionTwoAnswer)) {
            return questionTwoAnswer.getText().toString();
        }

        else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private String questionThreeGetAnswer() {
        if (!isEmpty(questionThreeAnswer)) {
            return questionThreeAnswer.getText().toString();
        }

        else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private String questionFourGetAnswer () {
        String returnString = "";

        if (questionFourAnswerOne.isChecked()) {
            returnString += questionFourAnswerOne.getText();
        }

        if (questionFourAnswerTwo.isChecked()) {
            returnString += " " + questionFourAnswerTwo.getText();
        }

        if (questionFourAnswerThree.isChecked()) {
            returnString += " " + questionFourAnswerThree.getText();
        }

        return returnString;
    }

    public void checkAnswers(View view) {
        String[] givenAnswers = {questionOneGetAnswer(), questionTwoGetAnswer(), questionThreeGetAnswer(), questionFourGetAnswer()};

        int right = 0;
        int wrong = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < givenAnswers.length; i++) {
            if (givenAnswers[i].equals(correctAnswers[i])) {
                right++;
            }

            else {
                wrong++;
            }
        }

        String message;

        if (wrong == 0) {
            message = "You got all the questions right!";
        }

        else {
            message = "Respuestas correctas: " + right + "\nRespuestas incorrectas: " + wrong + "\n¡Inténtalo de nuevo!";
        }

        //Reset answer fields
        // QUESTION 1
        questionOneAnswers.clearCheck();

        // QUESTION 2
        questionTwoAnswer.setText("");

        // QUESTION 3
        questionThreeAnswer.setText("");

        // QUESTION 4
        questionFourAnswerOne.setChecked(false);
        questionFourAnswerTwo.setChecked(false);
        questionFourAnswerThree.setChecked(false);

        // Print out message with quiz results
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AllElements">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#0D47A1</item>
</style>

<style name="Questions" parent="AllElements">
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can remove the below function and directly use 
**[TextUtils.isEmpty](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence))**

2) `questionThreeGetAnswer()` & `questionTwoGetAnswer()` can be refactor

```
 private String questionThreeGetAnswer() {
        return questionThreeAnswer.getText().toString();
 }
```

as `questionThreeAnswer.getText().toString()` always return **""**, if there is no data. So need to check for empty & return "".

#### Note:

In your case, `if-else` statement is useful only if you have to show an error for an empty answer.

Comment: Welcome :) glad to help you